# How would I prove this inequality regarding positive definite matrices.

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, numerical-linear-algebra

Let, $C,A,B \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times N}$, and $C$ and $A$ be hermetian. Suppose that,
$$C - B^{*}A^{-1}B,$$
is hermetian positive definite. How would we prove that,
$$||C||_{2} \ge ||B^{*}A^{-1}B||_{2}?$$
I know that for any $v \in \mathbb{C}^{n}$, we have that:
$$v^{T}Cv \ge v^{T}B^{*}A^{-1}Bv.$$
I don't know where to go from here. This question is relevant to block matrices, specifically if we have a block matrix $M$, and we wish to partition it into a $4$ by $4$ block matrix and get an inequality regarding its constituents.

Thank you!

Comment: Let $C=\mathbf 0$, $A=-I$, and $B\in GL_n(\mathbb C)$  then $C - B^{*}A^{-1}B = B^{*}B \succ \mathbf 0$ but $0=||C||_{2} \lt ||B^{*}A^{-1}B||_{2}$